# Rails Grape ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/user_locations"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, grape-api

I have used the grape and swagger for Rails backend - API application Rails 6

I have used the following gems for the

```
gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
gem 'grape-jbuilder'
```

I have created one controller UserLocations

```
 module API        
  module V1
   class UserLocations < API::V1::Base
   include API::Defaults

    resource :user_locations do
        desc 'Get User Locations',
              headers: {
           'Authorization' => { description: 'Authorization Header', required: true },
           'Access-Token' => { description: 'Access Token', required: true }
         }
        params do    
            
            optional :filter, type: JSON, desc: 'Filter object' do                  
                optional :gender, type: String, desc: 'Male/Female'
                optional :user_type, type: String, desc: 'User Type Guest/Registered'
            end       
            
        end

        get '/', jbuilder: 'user_locations/user_locations.json.jbuilder' do
            authenticate!
            binding.pry
            if params[:user_locations_ids].present?
                @users_locations = UserLocation.where(id: params[:user_locations_ids].map(&:to_i))
                return
            end
                @user_locations = UserLocation.includes(user: [:user_profile, :verification, car_detail: [:brand]])
                .select("user_profiles.username, user_profiles.gender, user_profiles.dob, user_profiles.user_type, 
                verifications.status, brands.name, user_locations.location_time, user_locations.city, 
                user_locations.state, user_locations.country, user_locations.postcode, user_locations.road")
                .references(user: [:user_profile, :verification, car_detail: [:brand]])
            end
                
        end          
    end
end
```

end
end

I have created the user_locations.json.builder file in user_locations folder in view

My routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 mount API::Base => '/api'
 mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/swagger'
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/user_locations"):
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

I need to Mount my new controller in base.rb

mount API::V1::UserLocations